# SQL CE ORMs for .NET CF

Tags: .net, orm, compact-framework, sql-server-ce

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate, but does anyone know of any (good) ORMs that work with SQL Compact Edition, and can run in the .NET Compact Framework (e.g. Windows Mobile 5->6.x)?

Comment: I would consider writing your own data access layer and using SqlCeDataReader or SqlCeResultSet.  A bit more work, but most mobile apps are simple enough for it not to be too time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

LLBlGenPro does, it's suppoosed to be good, have never tested myself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not shoe that LINQ is the full feature ORR, but have you tried `SqlMetal.exe Compact.sdf /dbml:Compact.dbml /namespace:Compact /serialization:Unidirectional /pluralize`?

P.S. LINQ is supported in the .NET Compact Framework version 3.5 and later.